# Setting conditions to access different variables for different hosts

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have two hosts currently configured in my /ansible/hosts file. However, I want these two hosts to have two different variables but use the same jinja2 template to access it. How can I apply the conditional statement?

My ./var/main.yaml looks like this:

```
---
- name: Variables for R1
  when: "{{ ansible_host }}" == '198.51.100.4'
  routers_all:
    - {OSPF: 'Yes', OSPF_area: '0', OSPF_id: '1', hostname: R1}
  int_details_R1:
    - {int: Loopback1, ip: 10.0.0.1, mask: 255.255.255.255}
    - {int: FastEthernet0/0, ip: 198.51.100.3, mask: 255.255.255.0}
    - {int: FastEthernet1/0, ip: 198.51.101.3, mask: 255.255.255.0}
    - {int: FastEthernet2/0, ip: 198.51.102.3, mask: 255.255.255.0}

- name: Variables for R2
  when: "{{ ansible_host }}" == '198.51.100.5'
  routers_all:
    - {OSPF: 'Yes', OSPF_area: '0', OSPF_id: '2', hostname: R2}
  int_details_R2:
    - {int: Loopback1, ip: 20.0.0.1, mask: 255.255.255.255}
    - {int: FastEthernet0/0, ip: 198.51.100.4, mask: 255.255.255.0}
    - {int: FastEthernet1/0, ip: 198.51.101.4, mask: 255.255.255.0}
```

The file structure-

```
automation@automation:~/lab8/ANSIBLE/RTR-TEMPLATE$ tree
.
├── ospf.yaml
└── roles
    └── router
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yaml
        ├── templates
        │   └── router.j2
        └── vars
            └── main.yaml
```

Comment: I cant give you exact jinja implementation but you can use https://gist.github.com/halberom/794c06598f40ccc31560 as reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use [host_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data). Create directory ~/lab8/ANSIBLE/RTR-TEMPLATE/host_vars and create the files with host-specific variables.

~/lab8/ANSIBLE/RTR-TEMPLATE/host_vars/198.51.100.4

```
routers_all:
  - {OSPF: 'Yes', OSPF_area: '0', OSPF_id: '1', hostname: R1}
int_details_R1:
  - {int: Loopback1, ip: 10.0.0.1, mask: 255.255.255.255}
  - {int: FastEthernet0/0, ip: 198.51.100.3, mask: 255.255.255.0}
  - {int: FastEthernet1/0, ip: 198.51.101.3, mask: 255.255.255.0}
  - {int: FastEthernet2/0, ip: 198.51.102.3, mask: 255.255.255.0}
```

~/lab8/ANSIBLE/RTR-TEMPLATE/host_vars/198.51.100.5

```
routers_all:
  - {OSPF: 'Yes', OSPF_area: '0', OSPF_id: '2', hostname: R2}
int_details_R2:
  - {int: Loopback1, ip: 20.0.0.1, mask: 255.255.255.255}
  - {int: FastEthernet0/0, ip: 198.51.100.4, mask: 255.255.255.0}
  - {int: FastEthernet1/0, ip: 198.51.101.4, mask: 255.255.255.0}
```

These variables will be added by the "default vars plugin" as described in [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)